# Windows Nginx Inuput File not specified error

Tags: php, nginx, server, winginx

PROBLEM: Problem i am facing is when I open `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gives me `"No Input file Specified"`

I am trying to configure Nginx and php on Windows.
Nginx installed path is `E:\server\nginx`
php installed path `is E:\server\php`
PhpMyAdmin installed path is `E:\phpmyadmin\`
My Root directory path is `E:\server\www`

Following code is from `nginx.conf` file.

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;
   root E:\server\www;                  

   index index.php index.html;

   location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
} 

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
    alias E:/server/phpmyadmin/;
    try_files $uri /phpmyadmin/index.php =404;

       location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_index   index.php;
       fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
       include         fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
   }
}
```

I am running nginx and php from command prompt

```
cd `E:\server\nginx\
nginx.exe`

cd E:\server\php\
php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1
```

server runs fine. I can access `localhost/`
I can also access any .php file from www folder.

PROBLEM: Problem I am facing is when I open localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me `"No Input file Specified"`

Please tell me I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please check the file owner/owner group, and guarantee the access rights of you nginx process to your php admin file.

Answer (score 1):

Give this an attempt:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  root         E:\server\www;                  

  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location /phpmyadmin {
    alias E:/server/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      include       fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```